# Did Marco Polo really play Weiqi (Go)?

Tags: china, 12th-century, game

Somebody told me that until the twentieth century Marco Polo was the strongest westerner ever to play go (weiqi).  Is this true?  I can't find any reference to it.  Googling Marco Polo and go doesn't seem to bring up anything.

Comment: Could somebody please re-tag this problem.  I can't find any good tags

Comment: "somebody told me" - is there a source for that, or is that just hallway gossip?  Sometimes knowing the source of the original assertion can help guide the research.

Comment: I'm sure that he was one of the only western players of go until the 20th century.

Comment: given that the very existence of Marco Polo is now in question, and his ever having traveled to China almost certainly discarded as a fable, I'd be inclined to say no. Of course the author now known by the name may have laid hands on a set of rules somehow and learned to play from that, but lack of opponents would have prevented an Italian in that era from ever becoming a strong player.

Comment: Actually in the middle ages and earlier scholarship doubted Margo Polo's veracity; modern thought is Marco Polo was not apocryphal.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Polo#Authenticity_and_veracity